Can I update the type annotation of a variable over time?
I'm making a Blender addon, and part of the flow of one of its functions involves de-duplicating vertices and returning vertex and index lists. Part of the algorithm I'm using involves setting duplicate elements to None, then clearing those elements later using a comprehension. My problem comes from the fact that I'd like to update the type annotation of my vertex list over the course of the function to express that it can contain None, then later back to only containing vertices.
def deduplicate(vertices: list[Vertex])
    # gives error "Declaration "vertices" is obscured by a declaration of the same name"
    vertices: list[Vertex|None] = vertices.copy()
    
    # de-duplication logic
    ...
    
    # 
    vertices: list[Vertex] = [v for v in vertices if v != None]

I know I could just use different variables for each step or opt to not have type checking enabled, but the first feels cumbersome and un-pythonic, and the second leaves me without the benefits of the editor checking over my work. Did I miss something or can the type of a variable really never be updated?

Type annotations are mostly for the benefit of static type checkers. If that’s what you’re using them for, changing the annotation at runtime makes no sense/has no benefit.

using different variable names for different things will make the code clearer

Neither of you are answering the question as formulated. I didn't ask your opinion on the premise of my question, I asked if I had missed something and python actually does have a mechanism for updating the type annotation of a variable.

That’s why we put this as comments and not answers.

Type hints don't exist at runtime (Python does not use them for type enforcement, input validation, etc) so your description feels like what you actually want is some kind of runtime data validation without having to write your own code for that. Type hinting won't do this for you.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: What part of the description feels like that? It sounds like a perfectly normal request for a static type checking feature.

Mostly where redeclaring static types in the middle of a function is the opposite of static typing, that's going back to dynamic typing (just not as free as untyped). So when someone wants to do that, the actual solution is almost always one step earlier: in this case, using a new variable name based on the new data it represents, with typing specific to that data rather than the original data, is perfectly fine. And very pythonic.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Think of it more as declaring a new variable that just happens to have the same name – you can do this in languages like Rust, and it’s quite static. I agree that using multiple, distinguished variables is perfectly Pythonic, but there are a couple of important advantages: no old references hanging around and potentially eating memory*, and being able to keep a very concise variable name if commonly referenced without risking referring to the wrong one by mistake. You can achieve these using del, but that starts to look a bit weird. (* Python should detect this…)

The mypy type checker allows you to do this with the --allow-redefinition option, without changes to your example code.

By default, mypy won’t allow a variable to be redefined with an unrelated type. This flag enables redefinition of a variable with an arbitrary type in some contexts: only redefinitions within the same block and nesting depth as the original definition are allowed.

Simplified playground example:
foo: int = 5
foo: str = str(foo + 2)


Success: no issues found in 1 source file


In your example there's no way to update the annotation information of function-level variables because it's not stored anywhere at runtime. You may be able to change the __annotations__ attribute of module- or class-level variables but they really weren't intended to be used like that and you might find behavior to be unexpected or inconsistent.
See: How to get type annotation within python function scope?

I know I could just use different variables for each step or opt to not have type checking enabled, but the first feels cumbersome and un-pythonic

It's extremely Pythonic.
